How to increment version prior to publishing in GitHub packages
How to increment version prior to publishing in GitHub packages. We update version attribute everytime before we do ./gradlew publish
Snippet from build.gradle
group = 'com.company.user'
version = '0.0.1'
description = """user-service"""

If we build and publish using GitHub action, how do I auto increment version prior to running the publish command

Simple search on Gradle release Github actions shows this https://github.com/marketplace/actions/generate-version

I used the Gradle Release Plugin (https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release) successfully.
It checks for SNAPSHOT-Dependencies before the release and also has a built in autoVersioning (look for the Working in Continuous Integration in the docs). If you need, you can specify the versions manually, but you don't have to.
This is not specially made for GitHub actions, but from my experience with such vendor-bindings for projects where you plan long-term development or support I would not work with special plugins there - it will make a potential migration to another system harder.

A note about versioning:
Judging from your gradle snippet version = '0.0.1' you formally align to the major.minor.patch versioning pattern. With major versions representing breaking changes, minor versions bringing new features and patch versions bringing bug fixes.
I doubt, that it is ensured that every publishing either contains major, minor or patch changes exclusively. A steady increasing of one of these version digits may not be best practice nor offers clarity of the versioning.
Instead, I see two approaches that may suite your CI (Continues Integration) setup:

If you publish to a maven repository, you can use add a -SNAPSHOT suffix to you versioning for non-release builds. The maven-publish plugin will automatically add a build timestamp before uploading to the maven repository. The maven repository then manages to always serve the latest SNAPSHOT bild when the major.minor.path-SNAPSHOT artefact is requested.
If you have a centralized CI tool (e.g. jenkins, teamcity, ...) and just want to dinstinguish different builds of the same version, you can add the build number as suffix to the version. Most of the CI tools provide the build number as environment variable or other type of property. If building and publishing takes place locally, you have to manage the build number on your own. May use an environment variable or a gradle project property. Register a new task to your build.gradle, get the current build number, increment it before publishing and update the build number origin to the new value.

gradle example (not tested)

// may use ext.publishVersion in case of value update issues
def publishVersion = project.version

publishing {
    publications {
        myArtifact(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = artifactBaseName
            version = publishVersion
        }
    }
}

// example with gradle.properties file. Same approach (read, update) for env. variables
tasks.register("IncreaseBuildNumber") {
    // buildNumber property is stored in 'gradle.properties'
    newbuildNumber = project.property["buildNumber"] as Integer
    newbuildNumber = newbuildNumber + 1

    publishVersion = publishVersion + ".${newbuildNumber}"

    // update 'gradle.properties' file
    var propertiesFile = new File("${project.rootDir}/gradle.properties")

    doLast {
        var updatedContent = propertiesFile.getText('UTF-8').replace(
                "buildNumber=${project.version}",
                "buildNumber=${newbuildNumber }"
        )

        delete propertiesFile 
        new File(propertiesFile.toString()).write(updatedContent, 'UTF-8')
    }
}

tasks.named('publish').configure {
    dependsOn tasks.named('IncreaseBuildNumber')
}


My appologies... my solution does probably not fit your question. I've missed the detail that you build with github actions.
